# Bind Variables in order by in sql

Tags: java, sql, plsql

i have requirement to have different order by criteria that will be set by user from UI. e.g. it can be

```
order by a asc, b desc, c asc
```

or

```
 order by b asc, a desc, c desc
```

It can be any combination that i will make from UI. How can i pass this to order by in sql through java.

Comment: You can construct the order by  clause dynamically and append to the SQL

Comment: @SabinJose, variable bindings aren't supposed to be used for columns. Are you saying about placeholders `(?)` ?

Comment: @harshavmb Since java is used to execute the sql we can frame the where clause of the query based on user input

Comment: If it can be any arbitrary SQL expression from the UI then you will need to use dynamic SQL and make sure you are not exposed to injection attacks. If instead there are fixed parameters then we can construct a static `order by` clause using a `case` statement.

Comment: @SabinJose, yeah I agree we can frame the where clause, but here it is `order by` column not by where predicate.

Comment: @harshavmb why not the same can be done in `order by`